# Run multiple commands passed as an argument to a bash script

Tags: bash

Here's the very simple file `test.sh`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

$1
```

When I run `./test.sh "pwd; mkdir a;"`, it returns

```
./test.sh: line 3: pwd;: command not found
```

I tried to use '&' / '&&' / ';', but all don't work.
How can I run multiple command by arugment?

Comment: Try this The Logical OR Operator (||) for run multiple command refer https://www.howtogeek.com/269509/how-to-run-two-or-more-terminal-commands-at-once-in-linux/ this

Comment: ./test.sh; pwd; mkdir a

Comment: Could you explain why you need to pass a sequence of commands as an argument to a script?  While knowing the answer to your question might be useful to you, there may also be something else of use to you : learning how to avoid passing commands to the script in the first place, as using data passed to a script as code is often not optimal from a security / avoiding surprises and bugs standpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to make `bash` interpret a string (`$1`) as if it were a script or typed commands. There are two ways to do that:

1. Use `eval` builtin: `eval $1` instead of `$1`.
2. Run separate `bash` to evaluate the commands: `bash -c "$1"` instead of `$1`. Mind the quotes.

Comment: Thx! Then there is no way to solve this problem if I can't edit `test.sh`, right?

Comment: @mayTree you can create a temporary script with necessary content, make it executable and then pass its name as an argument to `test.sh`